# What is a fast way to get metadata about files in a folder that includes size using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
var myFileList = new List<MyCustomFileInfo>();
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomeDir");

foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
{
    myFileList.Add(new MyCustomFileInfo()
    {
        Filename = file.Name,
        ModifiedOn = file.LastWriteTime,
        SizeInBytes = (int)file.Length
    });
}
```

dir.GetFiles executes very fast, but when I start to access properties, it seems individual calls are made to the file system (which is slow).

**How do I rewrite this, so I can get all filenames, lastWriteTime and filesizes in an more effective manner?**

Nb.
The code is cut down to just illustrate the point. The real-world use-case I have is more complicated (a sync-thing), but this is the heart of the performance problem.

Comment: Which file system? Do you need to support FAT or is NTFS only ok?

Comment: I 'm not sure if/how this can be improved (suspect not), but getting any information on directory contents other than their names is going to be a performance hit no matter what.

Comment: Not completely sure, @ThomasW. It is a network share in my specific case, but you can answer in a generic manner that requires NTFS - it might help others, if it does not work for me. :)

Comment: Well, network shares *are* slow... How many files are there and what ping time do you have? Try `ping -l 512 <IP>` to have a reasonable amout of data.

Comment: Maybe you can also use Process Monitor to see how many requests are made across the network for getting one piece of information.

Comment: In your particular scenario, iterating over all files can't be improved significantly. It alsowon't detect file moves. The only real improvement is to detect actual changes and then act on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if using [`dir.GetFileSystemInfos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/806sc8c5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be faster.

EDIT:

I looked through the relevant code with dotPeek, <del>so maybe not</del> see below!

Either way, if you are deploying on Windows, you should be able to use the `FindFirstFile` family of Win32 native functions, which is what `.Length` etc. do under covers (though as you rightly assumed, they do `FindFirstFile` for the file's full path, and read that, etc.)

EDIT 2:

I looked through the code *again*, and it does look like `GetFileSystemInfos` should populate the FileInfos and DirectoryInfos with data from the underlying system calls. (You should be able to verify this by looking at the `_dataInitialised` private field on the *Info -- if it's zero, then it's initialized, if it's -1, then it's not).

Comment: GetFiles actually *does* use FindFirstFile underneath

Comment: I already tried GetFilsystemInfos, but a FileSystemInfo does not contain a Length (or similar) property, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @Kjensen: You can cast the FileSystemInfo into a FileInfo. FI is FSI's subclass.

Comment: I see, thanks. However, it seems performance is just as with GetFiles(), so I guess FileInfo also has to load size info for each file as it is accessed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is an absolutely normal approach. If it is slow, then.. buy SSD or make a RAID (SSD RAID preferably ^^).

If the problem, caused by "slowness", is irresponsible UI, then do it in a very simple manner: populate list of files with only names (this is fast) and then run a thread which will *fetch* additional data for each item in the list. Perhaps even use a virtual list to only fetch displayed currently data.

Other thing could be to cache recent results, so if you go back to previous directory, results will be available instantly without need to reload everything.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all files in a folder is an inherently slow operation, no matter what the underlying storage is.

You can improve performance in some cases by using [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of GetFiles and return an IEnumerable instead of an array or a List. This way you can avoid iterating over *all* the files if you use Take(), Skip(), First() and other functions that can return before enumerating everything. You could also use Enumerable.Select to convert the IEnumerable to your own classes although this would result in system calls for each file processed.

Unfortunately, this won't work in a sync scenario (context really matters here) if you want to compare the current file system state against a previous snapshot. In this case it's *far* better to use a FileSystemWatcher to wait for actual changes to the folder you want to sync before processing.

Once you detect changes in the folder, you can wait a bit for them to stop before processing the entire folder, or keep a record of all the change events and process only those files that have actually changed. FileSystemWatcher can miss events if a lot of operations are going on (eg. if you copy a repository of some thousand files) but typically you *will* get a notification that a file has changed in some way.

Things are rather easier if you are sure you are using NTFS. In this case you can enable journaling and get a list of all the files that have changed since your last check. You could also use the Volume Shadow service to read even opened files, use Transactional NTFS to modify files in a safe manner etc. These features require native calls but the [AlphaFS](http://alphafs.codeplex.com/) project provides a library over them.

Internally, AlphaFS uses the extended methods to search for files like [FindFirstFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In Windows 7+, this function can use a large buffer to improve performance.

Another bonus is that journalling or NTFS's Object IDs allow you to detect renames or file moves (which are essentially the same thing) and avoid an unnecessary file syncronization.

Answer (score -1):

In any case you should remove the function call from the loop continue test condition.

```
var myFileList = new List<MyCustomFileInfo>();
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomeDir");
var files = dir.GetFiles(); // called 1 time only

foreach (var file in files)
{
    myFileList.Add(new MyCustomFileInfo()
    {
        Filename = file.Name,
        ModifiedOn = file.LastWriteTime,
        SizeInBytes = (int)file.Length
    });
}
```

Comment: That won't help at all. GetFiles returns an array of file names, which is an IEnumerable, thus foreach will enumerate over that. GetFiles will be called only once either way.

Comment: @CMircea but if you have n files, the function `GetFiles()` is called n times and the IEnumerable is created n times, is it not? In my solution it is just called 1 time

Comment: @CMircea What happens if a file is added to `dir` while the loop is running? My version will not loop over this new file, while Kjensen version from the question will. Am I mistaken? Can you give a link to your comment please?

Comment: @MartinMeeser GetFiles is called only once. `foreach` iterates over the results of GetFiles. The two versions are identical

Comment: OK I see i was unaware of that. Thank you both. If there are no more downvotes I will not delete my answer so that others can learn this lesson too. That's what SO is about, is it not...